# jQuery BlockUI: Call a function on click overlay

Tags: jquery, plugins, blockui

I'm using jQuery BlockUI Plugin and I'd like to do "Javascript:history back();" after Click overlay to unblock.

```
$.blockUI()
$('.blockOverlay').attr('title', 'something').click($.unblockUI);
```

What do you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I removed the ".attr('title', 'something')" part because it's not really important in the context of this question:

```
    $('.blockOverlay').click( function() { window.history.back(); } );
```